# ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

This is the table I have created:

```
 CREATE TABLE Ticket_Type
 (
  t_type_id  NUMBER(1) PRIMARY KEY,
  CONSTRAINT check_t_type_id CHECK(t_type_id  > 0),
  t_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  t_type_price NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT check_t_type_price CHECK(t_type_price > 0),
  t_type_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
  t_type_end_date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT check_t_type_end_date CHECK((t_type_end_date = NULL) OR (t_type_end_date >= t_type_start_date)),
  CONSTRAINT unique_t_type_t_type_start_date UNIQUE(t_type,t_type_start_date)
  );
```

I tried to create this table but I was getting the following error message:

```
Error report -
ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint
02436. 00000 -  "date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to use a date constant or system variable,
           such as USER, in a check constraint that was not completely
           specified in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement.  For
           example, a date was specified without the century.
*Action:   Completely specify the date constant or system variable.
           Setting the event 10149 allows constraints like "a1 > '10-MAY-96'",
           which a bug permitted to be created before version 8.
```

I'm unable to figure out regarding where is the mistake I'm making.

I'm using Oracle version 12c SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (for the CHECK constraint) ...

```
t_type_end_date IS NULL
```

Also, when using your DDL code in apex.oracle.com (Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production), we get

```
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

this is caused by the line

```
CONSTRAINT unique_t_type_t_type_start_date UNIQUE(t_type,t_type_start_date)
```

Comment: @stranger: Great!